# Extracting Variable Names as Strings

Tags: python-2.7

For a list or list of lists of arbitrary length, how can I extract the list variable names as strings?

Let arr_1, arr_2,...,arr_n be array-like objects (e.g. lists).  Let iterlist = [arr1,arr2,...,arr_n].  I want to extract & store the variable name of each element of iterlist as a string.  I can do this for scalar-valued variables, but not for arrays / lists.

Case 1 - variable holds integer (works):

```
test_var = 10
var_name = [m for m,n in locals().iteritems() if n == test_var][0]
print var_name 
--> test_var
```

Case 2 - variable holds array-like object:

```
test = [10, 20, 30, 40]
test_name = [k for k,v in locals().iteritems() if v == test][0]    

Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "...Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site- 
packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
File "<ipython-input-7-75ec0dff3986>", line 1, in <module>
test_name = [k for k,v in locals().iteritems() if v == test][0]
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Case 3 - list of lists:

```
var1 = 10
var2 = 15
iterlist = [var1, var2]
var_names = [k for k,v in locals().iteritems() for y in iterlist if v==y][0]
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I get the same 'dictionary changed size during iteration' array in both cases. 
I am aware that in Python, variables are just name mappings to objects, which (to me) implies no canonical names exist for variables (I think they do for classes).  My approach is a reverse search for the variable name. "iteritems" returns a list of all variables in the scope with their values. I am aware that you cannot add/remove elements in a dictionary while iterating through it. But I'm not able to isolate exactly where / when that's occurring here (don't know locals() & iteritems() well enough to attribute).

What am I missing?!

Comment: My guess is that within the scope of the list comprehension, the variables `k` and `v` get added to `locals()`.  But this seems like an XY problem; any time the question is something like "How can I have dynamic variable names from strings?", the answer is "Just use a dictionary."

Comment: Indeed.  I'm trying to avoid the dictionary route.  Also interested in understanding precisely what's going on, mainly from an educational perspective.  But valid point. I'll give your guess some thought.  Thanks.